# Trying to import component but getting error

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a Tetris game and a created a component (StyledDisplay), which I an trying to import but I am getting an error for my Display.Js page that says the following:

> Attempted import error: 'StyledDisplay' is not exported from
>   './styles/StyledDisplay'.

I know it's a very dumb question, but can someone look at how I am importing and exporting it?  I was fairly confident I was exporting the file and importing it the correct way, but a new set of eyes would not hurt.

This is how I have my Display.js folder, which is where I am importing:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyledDisplay } from './styles/StyledDisplay';

const Display = ({ gameOver, text }) =>(

<StyledDisplay gameOver={gameOver}>{text}</StyledDisplay>

)
export default Display;
```

This is how I have my Displayed.Js folder, which is where I created the component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const StyledDisplayed = styled.div`
    box-sizzing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 4px; solid #333;
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: ${props => (props.gameOver ? 'red' : '#999')};
    background: #000;
    font-family: Pixel, Arial, Helvetica, sans-seriff;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
`;
```

This is how I have my files set up in Visual Studio Code:
[image]

Comment: You're importing ```{StyledDisplay}```, but your component is called ```StyledDisplayed ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your export is named `StyledDisplayed` not `StyledDisplay`.

---

You also appear to have some additional typos like `box-sizzing` and `sans-seriff`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `export const StyledDisplayed` to `export const StyledDisplay.`

P.S. You have misspellings in your CSS that might cause weird visuals.